# YouTubeデータAPIが「視聴回数」の順序で機能しない

Tags: api, youtube

私はyoutubeデータAPIを使用しています。 ただ、視聴回数でのソートの結果は、YouTubeのGUIでのフィルタリング結果とは異なります。
APIのバグでしょうか。

Comment: 内容が漠然としていますね。ヘルプのこの辺の記事を参考に、質問を詳細化してみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: thank you